# Do all versions of an arXiv paper appear in Google Scholar?

Tags: arxiv, databases, google-scholar

I know that new arXiv papers usually appear in Google Scholar within a few days or weeks. My question is: if someone submits a replacement of his/her arXiv paper, does the new version of the paper also appear in Google Scholar?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how Google Scholar works. Papers are not 'submitted' there - Google will just index everything it finds with normal crawling that looks like a research paper in Scholar. That means that Scholar will also sooner or later pick up all updates you do to an article, just like the regular web search will also automatically pick up when you change your web site.

Comment: @xLeitix I know that papers are not submitted to Google Scholar and that GS just indexes them. When I say that a paper "appears" in GS, I mean that you can find the record of that paper in GS's database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remember that the way the arxiv works, the default paper identifier goes to the most recent version that's been uploaded. So even if Google Scholar caches an older version, it's using the same URL. Now if you make changes like changing the title and/or material parts of the abstract, then it might take a while for the new title to percolate through the search indices.