# Old version of an arXiv paper has been removed from Google scholar along with its citations

Tags: citations, arxiv, google-scholar

I've uploaded a new version of a paper to arXiv, but the old version doesn't appear on Scholar. On the other hand, I've merged the conference version of the paper and the new arXiv version and they do appear. Is it possible that you cannot have 3 version of the same paper on Scholar? Is there a way to get those citations back? Is there someone to talk to at Google Scholar about this issue?

Comment: Sometimes citations disappear and reappear.  Probably they will reappear at some point if they were correct.  Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/20172/19607

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Google scholar can track other versions of the same work within itself, although for title discovery, only the most recent version tends to be primarily indexed.

Google Scholar usually first indexes papers appearing within 7-14 days of their original announcement in arXiv, and then again within 2-3 days for minor tweaks that might have occurred after announcement. Any subsequent replacements or other metadata changes will appear in Google Scholar during their twice-yearly full system reindex, where they re-harvest all their data sources (details are at item number 1 in [their documentation](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#troubleshooting)). Typically these indices occur in January and July. No prior notice is given to arXiv that they are occurring, so arXiv cannot provide you with specifics regarding dates for the next harvest.